# How to read or download an entire folder/directory from WEB in java

Tags: java, android

I already know how to download a single file, but I want to download an entire folder/directory form a website using java

from private static String file_url = "http://umsurvey.comlu.com/admin/question/";

to OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Question/");

Comment: Perhaps Apache Commons VFS may be of help? It seems to be able to read directories via HTTP: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/filesystems.html#HTTP_and_HTTPS

Answer (score 1):

HTTP does not know about folders. 
Even there is no way to list individual file URLs inside "folder". So basically, what you are trying to do is not possible.